# What is the difference between "git push origin <branch>" and "git flow feature publish"?

Tags: git, git-flow

Both of these commands will push the code to the respected branch so that the other developers can work on that branch. Then what is the exact difference between these two commands?

Comment: `git push <remote> <branch>` is the standard way that everyone recognizes and that works without extensions, and `git flow feature publish` is probably a silly wrapper around it but I still haven’t found out for sure because there is no documentation.

Comment: @Ry- Well, it wasn't as straightforward as it's now with the answer from @KernelKoder: `git flow publish` configures the under-the-hood properties that ensure that branch is properly merged - instead of squashing commits into `develop` without a trace. So, in this case, `git push` is considered harmful.

Comment: @vintproykt: No, `git push` is perfectly fine if you know how to make merge commits.

Answer (score 5):

When doing `git flow feature publish` a few additional commands are run in the background by `git-flow`:

Pushes the branch 
`git push origin my-feature`

Configures the remote property on the branch 
`git config “branch.my-feature.remote” “origin”`

Configures the merge property on the branch 
`git config “branch.my-feature.merge” “refs/heads/my-feature”`

Checks out the branch 
`git checkout “my-feature”`

Comment: There's what seems to be a fairly good breakdown of what all the git-flow commands do at this gist: https://gist.github.com/JamesMGreene/cdd0ac49f90c987e45ac. The summary would be: anything extra to ensure you are doing the 'right thing' (like enforcing that finished features are merged onto develop etc...)

Comment: What some people don't seem to readily recognise is that you `git flow feature publish` once to establish and configure the remote branch, whereas you can repeatedly `git push` to update the remote with further changes.

Answer (score -2):

I didn't hear about `git-flow` before this question but it is a collection of Git extensions to provide high-level repository operations for Vincent Driessen's branching model, it can be found on [github](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow)

That basically means that you can not use it unless you install the add on.

So, `git push origin` works every where, `git flow feature publish` only works on systems that have the additional feature installed.

Comment: Just to clarify: you can use the Driessen branching model without installing git flow, but there's more typing. Installing git flow provides convenient shortcut commands.